# How to properly read zip file to String?

Tags: java, string, zip

I am encountering a problem when trying to read zip file to String. My goal is to read the file to String without unzipping it.

I want my file to look like this:
[Screenshot of the correct file opened in notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UbW3.png)

However when I read my file using this method and save this String to file:

```java
        String content = "";
        try {
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file2.getAbsolutePath())), "Windows-1250");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I end up with file looking like this: [Screenshot of incorrect file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prZoD.png)

These two as so similar yet different - the second one is not a valid zip archive [Screenshot of the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZMBz.png)

I was thinking that maybe it's the case of wrong character encoding - but I have tried so many of them and none seems to work - Windows-1250 looks closest to correct.

I am still a beginner so I wouldn't be surprised if I was missing something important here.
Please help!

Comment: You should not read a zip archive into a String without uncompressing it. String's deal with text. A zip archive is a binary file. Perhaps you could read it into a byte[].

Comment: There is no correct character set for this kind of task. Why are you trying to go that `String` detour instead of copying the file directly, i.e. as a sequence of bytes?

Comment: I wanted to pass it on in SOAP
like such:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 

          ......
          
                                        <ucm:Contents>" + HERE MY ZIP FILE + "</ucm:Contents>
                                    </ucm:File>
                                </ucm:Document>
                            </ucm:Service>
                        </ucm:GenericRequest>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: How is the receiving end supposed to understand which character encoding you used for the embedded string when it isn’t matching the encoding of the xml request? How about using a SOAP API/library that has a working mechanism to transfer binary content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my approach to this problem and instead of sending this file as content I am sending it as attachment.
This is code that works for me:

```
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();


    //Authenticate
    String authString = "LOGIN" + ":" + "PASSWORD";
    String enc = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((authString).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    MimeHeaders hd = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + enc);




    // SOAP Header
    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "/fscmService/ErpIntegrationService");

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("erp", "http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/");
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("typ", "http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/types/");

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    .
    .
    .
    CREATING MY SOAP BODY
    .
    .
    .


    AttachmentPart attachment = soapMessage.createAttachmentPart();


    File file = new File(MYFILE.ZIPDIRECTORY);

    InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    attachment.setRawContent(targetStream, Files.probeContentType(file.toPath()));

    attachment.setContentId(fileName);

    soapMessage.addAttachmentPart(attachment);

    soapMessage.saveChanges();
```

This way I can send my file correctly.